# Air Pressure Opens and Closes Doors

Tags: repair, doors, carpentry

We have an issue in a restaurant. When the front door is open, back door in kitchen closes. When Back door is open, front door closes.

After reading, this is due from airflow through the place, and moving air generally has less pressure than the static air in the rooms. This pressure difference pushes the other doors shut.
Question is, how do I fix the issue? Its one of the glass doors.

Comment: This is why skyscrapers need revolving doors.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because restaurants are not DIY home improvement.

Answer (score 2):

You have negative air pressure in the kitchen from the powerful blowers that pull smoke and steam through the hoods over the cooking areas. If you add make-up air vents served by a duct to bring outside air into the kitchen, your door problems will be solved.

The outdoor openings need wire mesh to keep birds and animals out, plus replaceable or washable dust filters to keep outdoor dust and pollen out of your kitchen. A damper in the duct will allow you to adjust the make-up air.

You will also find that your hoods work much better if they are not starved for air and sucking doors open.

Do you want proof before you invest in duct work? After business hours, turn off the kitchen hood blowers, then check your doors for normal operation. Voila, normal doors that don't open and close by themselves.

Comment: If this were the cause, then closing one door would make the other close more rapidly. The best explanation is the simplest - through draft.

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix is to use door stops.

Triangle pieces of rubber(whatever) wedge under door to stop movement.